# SQL Get Matrix from a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where I have a QUEUE column which have 5 different Queues , and Status of these queues is mentioned in 3 different columns.

I want to create a table of all which has all queue names in a column and all status to that in another column and 3rd column as the count..

What I tried is :-

```
SELECT Queue,Audit_Status,QC_Status,Shipping_Status,count(Queue) as Count FROM loans_table OGROUP BY Queue,Audit_Status,QC_Status,Shipping_Status
```

What I got :-

[image]

What I need : -

[image]

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - and take a look at COALESCE() too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a subqyery based  on union

```
select Queue, status , count(*)
from( 
    SELECT Queue
        ,Audit_Status status
    from loans_table
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT Queue
        ,QC_Status
    from loans_table
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT Queue
        ,Shipping_Status
    from loans_table) t 
group by Queue, status
```

Comment: @scaiseEdge , exactly what I was looking ,  just add ----where status is not null-- in your answer before last line